# A bug with collapsing when scrolling in Web App for Telegram Bot

Tags: javascript, html, flutter, web-applications, telegram

I want to build my mobile web application written in flutter in Telegram. At the same time, there is a problem: when scrolling down, the application collapses, as if I were collapsing the bottom sheet.

[Web App](https://m.nespat.app); [Telegram Web App](https://t.me/Nespat_bot/nespat); [Video demonstration of the problem](https://vimeo.com/851949100)

I managed to work around this problem for iOS devices by adding the following script to the code:

```js
document.addEventListener("touchmove", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
},
    {
        passive: false
    });
```

But on Android, the problem persists. I tried all the variations of working with touchmove, overflow, relative and other ways to disable scrolling on the page. The problem on Android has not been solved by any method that I have found.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the body section in the css to disable any touch events:

```
body {
    touch-action: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Not op here, I've tried this and it only works sometimes. I can scroll but after a while it randomly locks in place. @Zak, do you know why?

Comment: I had issues when I used scrollable modals, the scrolling in modals confuses the scrolling in main page, so I decided to stop using modals for longer contents, my pages works just fine

Comment: I'm not using scrollable modules. I am using addeventlistener("touchstart") and "touchmove" though. Is there anything I should avoid or additional code I need to use your answer?

Comment: I have the code hosted on GitHub at https://github.com/botfi-app/botfi-wallet , kindly check it out to learn how i did it

Comment: I ended up removing the modals and making them standalone pages