# Telegram webapp scrolling issue

Tags: html, telegram, viewport

I'm building app with Bubble.io and use it in Telegram webapp. When I pull down (scrolling up) on top of the page Telegram recognise it as close gesture and trying to minimize the window of app.

Maybe someone could explain me how it works and knows how it can be fixed?

Thanks

I tried ton of things but nothing works. I know that it is 100% possible and problem lay down somewhere in viewport/scroll/position setting.
The same problem I saw on forums of Flutter apps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A bug with collapsing when scrolling in Web App for Telegram Bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76842573/a-bug-with-collapsing-when-scrolling-in-web-app-for-telegram-bot)

Comment: Thank you but nope - it just kills scrolling

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it helped me to remove fixed height values from containers (height, max-height)

Comment: Should I do that in Bubble or on HTML?
Height 100% is fixed or not?
Thanks!

Comment: I can't say about Bubble, I used react. But I removed the hard-coded height values in all pages \ containers - inside which I needed vertically scrollable content, and now I'm trying to avoid this - the problem no longer arose