# How to disable closing telegram web app by swiping down?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'm creating an application with React Js. There's a game in TG Web app. You need to remove the balls by collecting combinations. But when I swipe down Tg wants to close.[The game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/do089.png)

I tried adding `touch-action : none` but it doesn`t work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A bug with collapsing when scrolling in Web App for Telegram Bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76842573/a-bug-with-collapsing-when-scrolling-in-web-app-for-telegram-bot)

Answer (score 0):

app.isClosingConfirmationEnabled = true;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).